# What is wrong with this excel if error formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to get a return on the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((Sheet5!$D$2:$D$7=B$1)*(Sheet5!$D$2:$D$7="Review"),
ROW(Sheet5!$A:$A),""),$A2),"???")
```

I am trying to use this formula to return the row numbers that meet the criteria of Complete and Reviewed in order to do a summary report for all the project ID's that meet this criteria. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Data set:

```
Project ID  Description Region  Status      Stage
1           Test 1      LATAM   In process  Review
2           Test 2      US_CA   In process  Review
3           Test 3      APAC    Complete    Review
4           Test 4      US_CA   In process  Review
5           Test 5      LATAM   Complete    Review
6           Test 6      LATAM   Complete    Review
```

Comment: I notice your formula includes: `Sheet5!$D$2:$D$7="Review"` but in your sample data the word "Review" only appears in the fifth column which would be `E` (or above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks from your original formula:

- `Sheet5!$D$2:$D$7=B$1` - I guess Cell `B1` should be "Completed" given your text description. In your example it was linked to the word ID.
  You could link it to B$1 but then the cell needs to have "Completed" in that particular cell.
- `ROW(Sheet5!$A:$A)` - not a good idea in this case since it's an array formula that compares two ranges to each other. Limit it to the range your are comparing to i.e. row `2` to `7` defined by your other range `$D$2:$D$7`

---

Given your example I think the formula in my example, located in cell H2, should look like this:

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((Sheet5!$E$1:$E$7="Complete")*(Sheet5!$F$1:$F$7="Review"),
ROW(Sheet5!$A$1:$A$7),""),$A2),"???")}
```

The formula returns which row number that fulfill the criteria "Completed" and Review". It's an array formula, so enter it with Ctrl + Shift + Enter

---

The formula could of course also be, where your lookup values is a cell reference:

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((Sheet5!$E$1:$E$7=$E$1)*(Sheet5!$F$1:$F$7=$F$1),
ROW(Sheet5!$A$1:$A$7),""),$A2),"???")}
```

Where:

`$E$1` has to have the word "Completed" or "In progress"

`$F$1` has to have the word "Review"

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wizhi! Much appreciated!

Comment: I updated it a little, to clarify the examples better. Thank you for your kind words, glad it helped :). Please mark the question as solved (little grey ticker under voting buttons) if you think it's solved so other people can see it. [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Take care :)!